# Unity animation editor's object rotation is doing weird

Tags: unity, animation

When using the Unity timeline to create an animation or by using the animator itself, I am unable to properly rotate an object. Whenever I do rotate it, it will usually go something as follows: From 0 -> 20 = 0, -132, 67, -89 and then 20.

I have tried to manually set the rotation values, doing this does help, but this means that I will have to do everything manually which is a crap ton of work. I also did make an animation yesterday with the timeline animation with no problems at all, in the morning there were the same problems and I have no clue how it suddenly worked.

I have also tried selecting rotation in the animation window and changing Euler to Euler (Quaternion) or Quaternion itself. This doesn't work, it will only have a less spinning outcome.

I would like to know if anyone has any solutions for this problem. I am using Unity version: 2018.3.5f1.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: A rotation just shows this curve: http://prntscr.com/oshfln

Comment: Can you describe the ultimate motion that you want the object to have? Or better yet, show us an example of a similar motion working as desired?